# Trying to understand process privilege attributes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-kernel

I'm writing a logging service that may collect privileges of a process and I'm trying to understand attributes for each process privilege. Let me explain with this code:

```
HANDLE hToken;
if(OpenProcessToken(::GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    if(!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, NULL, dwSize, &dwSize) &&
        ::GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        BYTE* pb = new (std::nothrow) BYTE[dwSize];
        if(pb)
        {
            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* pTPs = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*)pb;
            DWORD dwSize2;
            if(GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, pTPs, dwSize, &dwSize2) &&
                dwSize2 <= dwSize)
            {
                for(UINT i = 0; i < pTPs->PrivilegeCount; i++)
                {
                    //Analyze privilege attributes to understand if it's enabled or disabled?
                    DWORD dwPrivAttr = pTPs->Privileges[i].Attributes;

                    //...
                }
            }

            delete[] pb;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}
```

So let's see the structure of [TOKEN_PRIVILEGES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379630(v=vs.85).aspx) and `LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` in particular:

```
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT (0x00000001L)
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED            (0x00000002L)
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED            (0X00000004L)
#define SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS    (0x80000000L)
```

It looks like it is defined as a bitmask, but that brings up the following questions of interpreting these flags:

1. What is the difference between `ENABLED` and `ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT`?
2. What is `SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS` and how can it be used?
3. What if both `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` and `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` are set? Or, reset?
4. I just ran a simple test and for my process the `SeShutdownPrivilege` privilege had those attributes set as `0`. So what is that supposed to mean?

I'm more confused over this structure, but I'll keep it at just these points for now.

Thank you!

Comment: Enabled by default means it's enabled when the token is created, as opposed to later via [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375202). If it gets removed from the token, then you shouldn't be able to enable it.

Comment: Some APIs toggle the required privilege for you, if it's present in the token, but usually you have to manually enable it. That's the case with [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `SeShutdownPrivilege`.

Comment: @eryksun: So when attributes is set to 0, this means that the privilege is off, correct? In that case what is the point for `GetTokenInformation` API to get me `SeShutdownPrivilege` with attr `0` and not give me the rest of the privileges? I mean, `SeTcbPrivilege` is probably also off along with 20 others, but it doesn't return it. Sorry, I'm just trying to understand the logic here.

Comment: @eryksun: Also to check for privilege being on or off, do I need to do `bool bEnabled = !!(dwAtt & SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED);` or `bool bEnabled = !(dwAtt & SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED);` or what?

Comment: `SeTcbPrivilege` is not just off. Unless you're running as a system service it shouldn't be present in the token at all. You can't add privileges; you can only enable, disable, or remove them. It's best to enable a privilege only as needed, especially since the state of a privilege gets inherited by a child process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take your questions in order:

1. `ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` means the privilege is one of those that is enabled when the process starts.  If you have `ENABLED` but not `ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` then the process has enabled the privilege explicitly.  If you have `ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` but not `ENABLED` then the process has disabled the privilege explicitly.
2. According to the documentation, `SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS` is set whenever the privilege is actually used.  You might use this for troubleshooting, e.g., to detect that you are setting privileges that you are not actually using, or to determine experimentally which privileges a particular system call needs.  (I've never checked whether this actually behaves as documented, though I have no reason to think otherwise.)
3. If both `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` and `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` are set, you've found a bug in Windows. :-)

   If neither `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` nor `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` are set, then the privilege is present in the token, and has not been removed, but is not currently enabled.  You can enable it (or remove it) with [AdjustTokenPrivileges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202(v=vs.85).aspx).
4. If the attribute is zero, then the privilege is present in the token but is not currently enabled, has not been removed, was not enabled by default, and has never been used by the process.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, if a privilege has only `ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` then it is `off` or **not** enabled for that process, correct?

Comment: Technically enabled by default is just for when the token is created, right? i.e. `LogonUser`. This lets you know which privileges have been manually enabled, as opposed to privilege that were enabled by default when the token was created.

Comment: @eryksun: OK. But then it means the privilege is `on` contrary to what Harry said in his item 1. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @c00000fd, I don't think I contradicted the answer. I was just adding that it isn't a function of process creation, but rather token creation. A process is created with a duplicated token, which may inherit an enabled privilege that wasn't default enabled when the user was logged on.

Comment: @eryksun: I wasn't challenging you either. I just want to clarify that if `ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` bit is on and `ENABLED` bit is off, does that mean that the privilege itself is currently `off`?

Comment: @c00000fd, quote: *"If you have `ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` but not `ENABLED` then the process has disabled the privilege explicitly."* I would only add, as a point of clarification, that it may have been an *ancestor* process that disabled the privilege.

Answer (score 0):

What some of us may need to be told explicitly is that privileges have THREE possible states, not just two. As I began researching this stuff, I thought that a process would either have, or not have a privilege. But it turns out that even if the process has a privilege, it can be in a disabled state. In other words, disabled != doesn't have it.

The rest follows logically. If a privilege is not present in the process' access token, the process does not have that privilege. And vice versa, if the process does not have a privilege, the privilege will not be present in the token.

If the process has the privilege, the process can enable or disable it at will, right? Why is this useful? All right, I can guess that this allows you to call library functions without fully knowing what they do, and have them fail if they do more than you thought... Odd though.