# How to determine whether a process's privilege exists and its enabled/disabled?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, process, pinvoke

### SCENARIO

---

I would like to determine whether the specified process has enabled a specific **[privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

To make things easier for this question, the example target process will be the current process, and I'll check for the right to shutdown the local system (previouslly enabled with **[AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** function).

Then, I found the **[PrivilegeCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** function that seems can determine whether a specified set of privileges are enabled in an access token of a target process.

### UPDATE

I think that I focused on the wrong direction, because seems that the `PrivilegeCheck` function needs impersonation, so now I'm facing another neverending *trial-and-error* phase trying the **[GetTokenInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671(v=vs.85).aspx)** function, which seems the proper function to realize this task.

### PROBLEM

---

The problem I have is that when I try to use the `PrivilegeCheck` function, it always returns `False` (error), and the by-reference array of privileges does not have the expected values (because the function failed).

### UPDATE

The `GetTokenInformation` function fails too with a **False** value, returning this win32 error code: **122** (HRESULT: **-2147467259**) with message:

> Data Area Passed to a System Call Is Too Small

### QUESTION

---

What I should do to fix the errors I'm getting on my code to be able check whether a process's privilege exists, and then, whether the privilege is enabled or disabled?.

Using `PrivilegeCheck` or `GetTokenInformation` functions, or just any other damn function that could determine the privilege state.

### SOURCE-CODE

---

This is a full copyable example (together with the p/invokes below) on where I'll demonstrate how I'm testing both the `PrivilegeCheck` and the `GetTokenInformation` methodologies, both fails.

```
Dim pHandle As IntPtr = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle
Dim privilegeName As String = "SeShutdownPrivilege"
Dim tokenAccess As TokenAccess = (TokenAccess.AdjustPrivileges Or TokenAccess.Query Or TokenAccess.Duplicate)
Dim hToken As IntPtr
Dim hTokenDup As IntPtr

Try
    ' ****************************************************************************
    ' 1st Step: Enable the "SeShutdownPrivilege" privilege in the current process.
    ' ****************************************************************************

    Dim win32Err As Integer

    ' Get the process token.
    NativeMethods.OpenProcessToken(pHandle, tokenAccess, hToken)

    ' Set up a LuidAndAttributes structure containing the privilege to enable,
    ' getting the LUID that corresponds to the privilege.
    Dim luAttr As New LuidAndAttributes
    luAttr.Attributes = TokenPrivilegeAttributes.PrivilegeEnabled
    NativeMethods.LookupPrivilegeValue(Nothing, privilegeName, luAttr.Luid)

    ' Set up a TokenPrivileges structure containing only the source privilege.
    Dim newState As New TokenPrivileges
    newState.PrivilegeCount = 1
    newState.Privileges = New LuidAndAttributes() {luAttr}

    ' Set up a TokenPrivileges structure for the previous (modified) privileges.
    Dim prevState As New TokenPrivileges
    prevState = New TokenPrivileges
    ReDim prevState.Privileges(CInt(newState.PrivilegeCount))

    ' Apply the TokenPrivileges structure to the source process token.
    Dim bufferLength As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(prevState)
    Dim returnLength As IntPtr
    If Not NativeMethods.AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, False, newState, bufferLength, prevState, returnLength) Then
        win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
        MessageBox.Show("AdjustTokenPrivileges failed.")
        Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)
    End If

    ' *********************************************************************
    ' Everything OK at this point, 
    ' as AdjustTokenPrivileges dididn't failed, I assume the privilege Is enabled in the process.
    '
    ' 2n Step: Check whether the privilege is enabled or not...
    ' *********************************************************************

    ' Set up a new one LuidAndAttributes structure containing the privilege to check,
    ' getting the LUID that corresponds to the privilege.
    luAttr = New LuidAndAttributes
    NativeMethods.LookupPrivilegeValue(Nothing, privilegeName, luAttr.Luid)

    ' *********************************************************************
    ' Trying PrivilegeCheck and Duplicatetoken methodology...
    ' *********************************************************************

    NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(hToken, SecurityImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation, hTokenDup)
    win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error

    If (hTokenDup <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim pSet As New PrivilegeSet
        pSet.Control = 0
        pSet.PrivilegeCount = 1
        pSet.Privileges = New LuidAndAttributes() {luAttr}

        If Not NativeMethods.PrivilegeCheck(hToken, pSet, result) Then
            win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
            MessageBox.Show("PrivilegeCheck using original access-token failed.")
            ' Ignore exception, to continue with the GetTokenInformation methodology.
            ' Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)

        Else
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} (original token) state is: {1}",
                                              privilegeName, pSet.Privileges(0).Attributes.ToString()))

            If Not NativeMethods.PrivilegeCheck(hTokenDup, pSet, result) Then
                win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
                MessageBox.Show("PrivilegeCheck using impersonated access-token failed.")
                ' Ignore exception, to continue with the GetTokenInformation methodology.
                ' Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} (impersonated token) state is: {1}",
                                              privilegeName, pSet.Privileges(0).Attributes.ToString()))

            End If

        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("DuplicateToken failed.")
        ' Ignore exception, to continue with the GetTokenInformation methodology.
        ' Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)

    End If

    ' *********************************************************************
    ' Trying GetTokenInformation methodology...
    ' *********************************************************************

    Dim tkp As New TokenPrivileges
    Dim tkpHandle As IntPtr
    Dim tkInfoLength As Integer = 0

    tkpHandle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tkpHandle))
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(tkp, tkpHandle, False)

    NativeMethods.GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenInformationClass.TokenPrivileges, IntPtr.Zero, tkInfoLength, tkInfoLength)
    win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
    ' If I understood, It is supposed to return 122,
    ' so I should ignore that error code?:
    If (win32Err <> 122) Then 
        MessageBox.Show("GetTokenInformation failed in the attempt to get the TokenPrivileges's size.")
        Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)

    Else
        If Not NativeMethods.GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenInformationClass.TokenPrivileges, tkpHandle, tkInfoLength, tkInfoLength) Then
            win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
            MessageBox.Show("GetTokenInformation failed in the attempt to get the TokenPrivileges.")
            Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)

        Else
            Dim privilegeAttr As TokenPrivilegeAttributes = tkp.Privileges(0).Attributes
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} state is: {1}", privilegeName, privilegeAttr.ToString()))

        End If

    End If

Catch ex As Win32Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.NativeErrorCode & " " & ex.Message)

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

Finally
    If (hTokenDup <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hTokenDup)
    End If

    If (hToken <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hToken)
    End If

End Try
```

And these are the related winapi definitions (notice the commented MSDN urls for interest):

```
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function OpenProcessToken(ByVal processHandle As IntPtr,
                                        ByVal desiredAccess As TokenAccess,
                                        ByRef tokenHandle As IntPtr
) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping:=False, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True)>
Public Shared Function LookupPrivilegeValue(ByVal lpSystemName As String,
                                            ByVal lpName As String,
                                            ByRef lpLuid As Luid
) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function AdjustTokenPrivileges(ByVal tokenHandle As IntPtr,
                                             ByVal disableAllPrivileges As Boolean,
                                             ByRef newState As TokenPrivileges,
                                             ByVal bufferLength As Integer,
                                             ByRef refPreviousState As TokenPrivileges,
                                             ByRef refReturnLength As IntPtr
) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function PrivilegeCheck(ByVal token As IntPtr,
                          <[In], Out> ByRef privileges As PrivilegeSet,
                                      ByRef refResult As Boolean
) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function DuplicateToken(ByVal tokenHandle As IntPtr,
                                      ByVal impersonationLevel As SecurityImpersonationLevel,
                                      ByRef duplicateTokenHandle As IntPtr
) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function GetTokenInformation(ByVal tokenHandle As IntPtr,
                                           ByVal tokenInformationClass As TokenInformationClass,
                                           ByVal tokenInformation As IntPtr,
                                           ByVal tokenInformationLength As Integer,
                                           ByRef refReturnLength As Integer
) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<Flags>
Public Enum TokenAccess As UInteger
    ' THIS ENUMERATION IS PARTIALLY DEFINED.
    ' **************************************
    TokenAdjustPrivileges = &H20UI
    TokenQuery = &H8UI
End Enum

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<Flags>
Public Enum TokenPrivilegeAttributes As UInteger
    PrivilegeDisabled = &H0UI
    PrivilegeEnabledByDefault = &H1UI
    PrivilegeEnabled = &H2UI
    PrivilegeRemoved = &H4UI
    PrivilegeUsedForAccess = &H80000000UI
End Enum

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379572(v=vs.85).aspx
Public Enum SecurityImpersonationLevel As Integer
    SecurityAnonymous = 0
    SecurityIdentification = 1
    SecurityImpersonation = 2
    SecurityDelegation = 3
End Enum

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure Luid
    Public LowPart As UInteger
    Public HighPart As Integer
End Structure

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure LuidAndAttributes
    Public Luid As Luid
    Public Attributes As TokenPrivilegeAttributes
End Structure

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure TokenPrivileges
    Public PrivilegeCount As UInteger

    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=1)>
    Public Privileges As LuidAndAttributes()
End Structure

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure PrivilegeSet
    Public PrivilegeCount As UInteger
    Public Control As UInteger

    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=1)>
    Public Privileges As LuidAndAttributes()
End Structure
```

Comment: The documentation for PrivilegeCheck says that the token "must have been obtained by opening the token of a thread impersonating the client", i.e., it must be an impersonation token.  I'm not certain, but I seem to recall reading somewhere that this is a firm requirement, that the function really will fail if given a primary token, which is what you're doing.  Try using DuplicateToken to convert the primary token to an impersonation token first.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Thankyou for notice that info of the documentation, I followed your suggestion, I ensured that the returned handle/token of `DuplicateToken` function is not zero/null, however, even using the new obtained token I still have the same problem described in my question, `PrivilegeCheck` functions fails returning **False**.

Comment: Anyways I'm not sure whether I should mess with user impersonation, I'm not any expert on that but I think that I'm not pretending to do something specific at that level that would require impersonation, because I just would like to determine if a privilege exists and its enabled on a target process on the local system and for the current logged user, so if `PrivilegeCheck` needs impersonation then maybe I focused on the wrong function and I should use a simpler function than `PrivilegeCheck` for what I need? which function would be then? any idea?.

Comment: IMO, the most useful thing you could do at this point would be find the Win32 error code that PrivilegeCheck is returning - IIRC, you need to add something to the P/Invoke function declaration, but I don't recall the details.  But if you want an alternative, you could always use GetTokenInformation and examine the privileges array yourself.  (I'm not sure of the proper way to compare two LUIDs, but on backwards-compatibility grounds a simple comparison of each of the structure elements *should* be safe.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston Really thanks for your time trying to help. The error code in decimal is **-2147467259** and error message is `Data Area Passed to a System Call Is Too Small`, I think it refers to the size of the managed `TokenPrivileges` struct, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong about that. PS: I did a big update on all the sections of my question if you would like to read.

Comment: I think that's the error code from the first call to GetTokenInformation, where you ask for the buffer size?  That's because you're passing NULL for the buffer but not specifying the buffer size as zero as documented.  That call is *supposed* to fail, but it should be error 122.  Then you're supposed to check the output value of `ReturnLength` and allocate a buffer of that size before making the second call.

Comment: What is the last error code returned from PrivilegeCheck?

Comment: Yes its the first call the error, but I'm specifying zero (tkInfoLength = 0) as the buffer size. About **PrivilegeCheck**, well, now I can't verify it with the duplicated token 'cause **DuplicateToken** fails with "Access Denied" message and error code: **-2147467259** so the dup handle is null.

Comment: Oh, does vb.net automatically initialize all variables to zero?  Didn't know that. :-)  I think you're not getting the error code correctly, -2147467259 is a generic HRESULT code, E_FAIL.  Neither DuplicateToken nor GetTokenInformation is going to return that and it doesn't translate to either "Access Denied" or to "Data Area ... Too Small".

Comment: So if I ignore the code and look at the messages ... GetTokenInformation is *expected* to fail the first time around, as previously mentioned.  DuplicateToken is probably because you don't have impersonation privilege, use `SecurityImpersonationLevel.SecurityIdentification` rather than `SecurityImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation`.

Comment: Yes in Vb.Net there is no need to call the default ctor, numeric datatypes are automatically initialized to Zero (and Bools to False), if you are a C# guy and if you maybe have a solution for that language, then I'll accept your answer written in C#. I tried with each value of the **SecurityImpersonationLevel** enumeration, I really can't understand why now I'm getting access denied. And sorry you've reason I was checking for the HRESULT instead the proper err, it returns err **122** as you said. It's too late here, tomorrow I'll verify the other error codes and I'll open a bounty for this :).

Comment: Oh, you probably just need to change the permissions in the call to OpenProcessToken.  You'll need to include TOKEN_DUPLICATE access.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Using the `TOKEN_DUPLICATE` flag solves the error, but didn't solved the question. On the **1st step** part of my code, If I use `TokenPrivilegeAttributes.PrivilegeEnabled` to enable the privilege on the current process, then both calls to `PrivilegeCheck` returns `TokenPrivilegeAttributes.PrivilegeUsedForAccess`,and,if I use any other value of the enumeration, then it returns `TokenPrivilegeAttributes.PrivilegeDisabled`.Also,at the last **Else** block,the `privilegeAttr` throws a null reference exception because `tkp.Privileges` member is null, so `GetTokenInformation` failed.

Comment: So both the calls to PrivilegeCheck are now working?  I guess the problem was the access rights to the token, rather than the type of token.  Probably if you pass PrivilegeCheck a primary token it converts it to an impersonation token automatically, but of course it needs TOKEN_DUPLICATE access in order to do that.  I'd still recommend doing it yourself, since that's what the documentation says.

Comment: Looks like the problem with GetTokenInformation is a buffer overflow.  You're telling it that the buffer `tkpHandle` is `tkInfoLength` bytes long, but unless I'm reading the .NET code incorrectly, you actually only allocated `Marshal.SizeOf(tkpHandle)`, i.e., 4 or 8 bytes depending on bitness.  You need to allocate the buffer *after* the first call to GetTokenInformation, once you know how big it needs to be.

Comment: After reading what [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202.aspx) actually returns I have updated [my LinqPad query](http://share.linqpad.net/i6xq35.linq) to report those results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I now uploaded the full code I used to test my answer, in case somebody else needs a working example. Especially the boilerplate there is not perfect (and wasn't intended to be), please don't judge me on that. See this paste: http://pastebin.com/gdxwWHRb*

---

You are incorrectly using the unmanaged memory block `tkpHandle` and the structure `tkp`. Also, you are just checking the attributes of the first privilege returned by `GetTokenInformation` (`tkp.Privileges(0)`) - instead, you have to check all and find the right one.

If I change your code like this, it works for me:

```
' *********************************************************************
' Trying GetTokenInformation methodology...
' *********************************************************************

Dim tkp As New TokenPrivileges
Dim tkpHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero ' <<< will be set later
Dim tkInfoLength As Integer = 0

' Here we call GetTokenInformation the first time to receive the length of the data it would like to store.
NativeMethods.GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenInformationClass.TokenPrivileges, IntPtr.Zero, tkInfoLength, tkInfoLength)
win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error

' Since the "current" length we pass is 0, we'll always get "error" 122, which is fine. We also get the required length returned.
If (win32Err <> 122) Then
    MessageBox.Show("GetTokenInformation failed in the attempt to get the TokenPrivileges's size.")
    Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)
Else
    Try
        ' Here we allocate memory for receiving the actual data. By now, tkInfoLength contains the size of the memory block we need to allocate.
        tkpHandle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(tkInfoLength)

        ' This time, we shouldn't get an error 122, because this time we already have set the correct buffer size. GetTokenInformation should now write the data into the memory block we just allocated.
        If Not NativeMethods.GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenInformationClass.TokenPrivileges, tkpHandle, tkInfoLength, tkInfoLength) Then
            win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
            MessageBox.Show("GetTokenInformation failed in the attempt to get the TokenPrivileges.")
            Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)

        Else
            ' We will now ask PtrToStructure to read the raw data out of the memory block and convert it to a managed structure of type TokenPrivileges which we can use in our code. That's it!
            tkp = Marshal.PtrToStructure(tkpHandle, GetType(TokenPrivileges))

            ' We have to iterate over all privileges listed in the TokenPrivileges structure to find the one we are looking for
            Dim found As Boolean = False
            For i As Integer = 0 To tkp.PrivilegeCount - 1
                ' There is a problem: Marshal.PtrToStructure can't marshal variable-length structures, but the array TokenPrivileges::Privileges has
                ' a variable length determined by the value of TokenPrivileges::PrivilegeCount! Since we don't know the size at compile time, the
                ' size of the array was hardcoded to 1, which means that we would only be able to access the first element of the array.
                ' To work around this, we calculate the raw memory offset pointing to the array element we need and load it separately into a
                ' LuidAndAttributes variable.
                ' The way this works is: The contents of the TokenPrivilege structure or stored in memory one after another, like this:
                '   PrivilegeCount (type: UInteger)
                '   Privileges(0) (type: LuidAndAttributes)
                '   Privileges(1) (type: LuidAndAttributes) << these and all further we normally can't access
                '   Privileges(2) (type: LuidAndAttributes)
                ' ...and so on.
                ' We are now calculating the offset into the structure for a specific array element. Let's use Privileges(2) as example:
                ' To get to it, we need to take the pointer to the beginning of the structure and add the sizes of all previous elements,
                ' which would be once the size of PrivilegeCount and then 2 times the size of a LuidAndAttributes structure.
                Dim directPointer As New IntPtr(tkpHandle.ToInt64() + Len(tkp.PrivilegeCount) + i * Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(LuidAndAttributes)))
                Dim luidAndAttributes As LuidAndAttributes = Marshal.PtrToStructure(directPointer, GetType(LuidAndAttributes))

                ' Get the privilege name. We first call LookupPrivilegeName with a zero size to get the real size we need, then reserve space, then get the actual data
                ' NOTE: The part below isn't actually necessary as commented Mark Hurd pointed out, because you already have the right privilege's LUID in luAttr.Luid.
                ' But I'll leave it here anyway in case somebody uses this piece of code without the part which sets the privilege.
                ' Another solution in this case would also be to run LookupPrivilegeValue to get the LUID to compare to (which is what led to luAttr.Luid as well).
                Dim privNameLen As Integer = 0
                Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
                NativeMethods.LookupPrivilegeName(Nothing, luidAndAttributes.Luid, sb, privNameLen)
                sb.EnsureCapacity(privNameLen + 1)
                If Not NativeMethods.LookupPrivilegeName(Nothing, luidAndAttributes.Luid, sb, privNameLen) Then
                    win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error
                    MessageBox.Show("LookupPrivilegeName failed.")
                    Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)
                End If

                ' Now that we have the name, we can check if it's the one we are looking for.
                ' NOTE: Refering to me comments above, this could be just: If luidAndAttributes.Luid = luAttr.Luid
                If sb.ToString() = privilegeName Then
                    ' Found! So we can finally get the status of the privilege!
                    found = True
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} state is: {1}", privilegeName, luidAndAttributes.Attributes.ToString()))
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If Not found Then MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} not found in list of privileges!", privilegeName))
        End If
    Finally
        ' Make sure the memory block is freed again (even when an error occured)
        If tkpHandle Then Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tkpHandle)
    End Try

End If
```

See my comments in the code. Basically, the flow is:

- Call GetTokenInformation with a null pointer and a zero size in order to receive the actually required buffer size (so error 122 is normal here).
- Allocate memory according to the buffer size we received.
- Call GetTokenInformation again, with the real pointer to the memory block and the real size in order to receive the actual data.
- Convert the raw data into a .NET structure using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` (not `Marshal.StructureToPtr`).
- Find the right privilege and check its status. This is a bit tricky, see my explanation below.
- Free the memory block. (I added a Try/Finally block to make sure the memory is never leaked.)

There is another tricky part here which is how to find the right privilege to check in the list of privileges returned by `GetTokenInformation`:

- `Marshal.PtrToStructure` can't marshal variable-length arrays like the one inside the `TokenInformation` structure. In order to be able to access the elements after the first one in our code, we have to play some tricks and do pointer arithmetic in order to calculate the memory offset of those array elements and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` for each of them individually. See my comments in the code for details.
- In order to know which privilege is which, we need to use `LookupPrivilegeName` which is basically the opposite of `LookupPrivilegeValue`. Note that again we first call it with a zero length to get the actual length, then reserve space, then call it again. - **NOTE**: As I wrote in my EDIT2, this isn't actually necessary if you are looking for a specific privilege. You just need to get the right LUID using `LookupPrivilegeValue` and then compare the LUIDs against the known one. And you already did that earlier in your code (it's in `luAttr.Luid`). Please read me additional comments in the code!

I imported `LookupPrivilegeName` like this:

```
<DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping:=False, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True)>
Public Shared Function LookupPrivilegeName(lpSystemName As String, ByRef lpLuid As Luid, lpName As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByRef cchName As Integer) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
```

Now the code successfully runs for me and shows a message box:

> SeShutdownPrivilege state is: PrivilegeEnabled

**EDIT**: I overlooked the problem that `tkp.Privileges(0).Attributes` was hardcoded instead of looping over all privileges to find the right one. I added the right solution to my answer.

**EDIT2**: As [commenter Mark Hurd pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683660/how-to-determine-whether-a-processs-privilege-exists-and-its-enabled-disabled/36862571?noredirect=1#comment61340240_36862571) correctly, there is actually no need to call `LookupPrivilegeName` every time. In the original code of this question, the LUID of the privilege is already known because it's earlier looked up using `LookupPrivilegeValue`. But I'll leave the name lookup in the code anyway, in case somebody needs to enumerate the other enabled privileges as well - I just added comments about it.

Comment: I haven't attempted to work out why, but something in this code seems to remember previous positive results. See this [linqpad query](http://share.linqpad.net/lx6rqb.linq). In summary, I've encapsulated this code into a subroutine and called it three times, once with `"SeSecurityPrivilege"`, where it correctly (according to `ProcExp`) shows that privilege was not enabled, then with `"SeShutdownPrivilege"` which succeeds, and finally with `"SeSecurityPrivilege"` again, and, this time, it says it is now held! (Because of this, remember to "Query > Cancel All Threads and Reset" between runs.)

Comment: Indeed, there is another problem with your code which I overlooked. You are always checking the state of the first privilege in the list (`Privileges(0)`). You would have to iterate over all privileges and call `LookupPrivilegeName` on them to get the name and compare it with the name you are looking for in order to find the right privilege entry for which you want to check the status. I am unfortunately not able to add the right code to my answer right now though, possibly later.

Comment: I added the solution to my answer now. Please also read the comments in the code! [PS: Just now I realized that you are not the one who posted the question, so it's of course not "your code" I was refering to.]

Comment: +1 (but I'd already given it to you before I noted the above issue). For LinqPad people following at home [my updated query](http://share.linqpad.net/7lw89e.linq).

Comment: BTW note you didn't really need to call `LookupPrivilegeName` on each `LUID` when you have the one you need to compare to in `luAttr.Luid`.

Comment: I cannot express the gratitude with words, just THANKYOU. It works with the privileges that I really interested to use (SeDebugPrivilege and the shutdown privileges) so no problem, but for curiosity I tried to test other privilege names like "SeAuditPrivilege" or "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege" and others, and they are not found in the privilege list returned, it is a mistake of your algorithm or the problem is other thing?.

Comment: The list returned will only contain privileges which have any attribute of interest for this token. So if you don't find it, you can assume it's not enabled for this token (but the opposite is not true). You can find a more detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453204/trying-to-understand-process-privilege-attributes

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explained it correctlly: I mean that after enabling specific privileges like "SeAuditPrivilege" in the target token process using AdjusttokenPrivileges (in the same way I can enable other privileges), the algorithm cannot find the mentioned privilege.

Comment: Are they listed in process explorer after you enabled them? Maybe enabling them fails already (maybe you don't have the necessary rights to enable them) - I didn't pay much attention to these parts of your code I have to admit, so I don't know if you are missing any error checks there...